# How can I add a style to a parent component when the input gets focused with styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How can I add a style to a parent component when the input gets focused with styled component?

When the `Input component` gets focused, I'd like to add border style to the `Container component`.

app.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Container, Input } from "./styles";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Input />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
`;

export const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  ${Input}:focus & {
    border: 5px solid #04435e;
  }
`;
```

Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be achieved using the `:focus-within`  CSS pseudo-class on the **Container** component.

##### styles.js

```js
export const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &:focus-within {
    border: 5px solid #04435e;
  }
`;
```